# Python - Copy sheet from multiple workbooks to one workbook

Tags: python, excel, spreadsheet

Here is my process:

Step 1: Open File1
Step 2: Load Sheet1
Step 3: Load OutputFile
Step 4: Create a new sheet in OutputFile
Step 5: Copy contents cell by cell from Step 2 to paste in the sheet created in Step 4
Step 6: Repeat the process 'n' number of times

I have created a Python script to achieve this but the program is insanely slow. Takes an hour to complete. Here is a snippet of the code that does the copying over.

```
import xlsxwriter as xlsx
import openpyxl as xl

for i in range (6,k):
    #get the file location/name from source file
    filename = sheet.cell_value(i,3)
    #get the sheetname from the sheet read in the above statement
    sheetname = sheet.cell_value(i,4)
    #print the file name to verify
    print(filename)
    #get output sheet name
    outputsheetname = sheet.cell_value(i,5)

    #load the source workbook
    wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=filename,data_only = True)
    #get the index of sheet to be copied
    wb1_sheet_index = wb1.sheetnames.index(sheetname)
    #load the sheet
    ws1 = wb1.worksheets[wb1_sheet_index]

    #load the output workbook
    wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=output_loc)
    #create a new sheet in output workbook
    ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(outputsheetname)
    #print(ws2,":",outputsheetname)

    for row in ws1:
        for cell in row:
            ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

    wb2.save(output_loc)

wb2.save(output_loc)
```

The filename, sheetname and outputsheetname comes from a master excel sheet where I keep the file location and sheet names. I load this file before this loop.

Also, I want the contents of the cell to be copied. If the source sheet has any formula, I do not want that to be copied over. And if there is a value 500 in Cell A5, I want the value to be in cell A5 in the output sheet.

Maybe I am approaching this the wrong way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl is the slowest module to work with excel file. you can try doing it with xlwings or if you're okay to use any excel add-in [here is the RDB Merge](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm) that you can prefer using it, it is comparetively fast and does work